# Java 8 https discord request

Tags: java, https, request

**Hello, I tried to get a response from a discord server using HttpsConnection, but the server responded with error 403 and I don't know why, I tried this code in JDK 13+ above and it worked, but I need JDK 8, but on this version it for some reason does not work.**

 The error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP
> response code: 403 for URL:
> https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/channels     at
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1897)
> at
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1495)
> at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
> at com.joojn.Main.main(Main.java:31)

```
String BASE_URL = "https://discord.com/api/v9";
String token = "superSecretToken";

String getChannelsURL = BASE_URL + "/users/@me/channels";
String getGuildsURL = BASE_URL + "/users/@me/guilds";

URL url = new URL(getChannelsURL);

HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("authorization", token);
        

InputStream content = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream(); // this is line 31
String text = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: I added an answer , if it satisfied your requirement i appreciate if you accept as answer ti improve the community otherwise feel free to comment  .

Comment: 403 means "Forbidden" - You have not provided any required credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your import statement for HttpURLConnection class from

```
import sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection;
```

to the

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
```

When you try the code with JDK 13+ above and it re-import the package

cause the sun package and related class in your application code are internal to JVM.

Comment: I didn't even use that package because I am using https not http, but tried that and it still does not work. And also I think it's like some problem with "connection.setRequestProperty("authorization", token);" because when i tried google.com it worked..

Comment: @joojn With assuming that token is valid which may nit have you add to set connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "your-api-contentype"); as well ?

Comment: I did not, but after adding still not working..

Comment: Problem found! I was missing "User-Agent"..

Comment: @joojn wonderful !As the place our discussion about setRequestProperty exist in comment as well  i appreciate if you accept it as answer .